# Oracle Cloud data service with Applications on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, oracle, database-performance

We're deploying an application that uses Oracle as the database backend, and as the application is deployed in AWS, we use AWS RDS for the Oracle database - and we have a lot of problems with that, as it looks like almost anything other than very basic Oracle features is either not possible at all or requires installing external services on EC2 (e.g. APEX server).

Supposedly Oracle offers Oracle database SaaS on the Oracle Cloud service, but we don't want to move our application to Oracle Cloud IaaS/Paas because that doesn't have all the infrastructure features that we need.

We also see that Oracle Cloud offers "VPN to premises" - so the question is: did anyone try and can share their experience about setting up a VPN between AWS and Oracle Cloud so we can run our application on AWS and the database on Oracle Cloud?

Comment: This is obviously something you'd want to test well, the latency could really impact performance. You can just install Oracle on an EC2 server you control, but then you have to maintain it.